# "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default" works in one module and not in another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two javascript files which are both used in the same web page and which both use the resources of a third javascript file.

The main JS file Person6.js, at /FamilyTree/Person6.js on the webserver:

```js
import HTTP from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
import {iframe, actMouseOverHelp, openFrame, openSignon, debug, args,
        getOffsetLeft, getOffsetTop, popupAlert, show,
        showHelp, hideHelp, helpElt, keyDown,
        eltMouseOver, eltMouseOut}
            from "../jscripts6/util.js";
import {capitalize} from "../jscripts6/CommonForm.js";
import Cookie from "../jscripts6/Cookie.js";
```

and CommonForm.js, at /jscripts6/CommonForm.js on the web server, which you see has one method imported by the main script.

```js
import HTTP from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
import {getOffsetLeft, getOffsetTop, popupAlert, 
        helpDiv, eltMouseOver, eltMouseOut, displayHelp}
            from "../jscripts6/util.js";
```

When I run eslint over each of these files individually there are no problems reported except undefined resources which are declared in scripts which are incorporated in the application through  tags:

```html
    <script src="/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js" type="application/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/FamilyTree/Person6.js" type="module">
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.43&callback=initializeMaps&region=$GOOGLECC&key=$GOOGLEKEY" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default CommonForm.js:157:7.
```

line 157 is import HTTP from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js"; as shown above.

Why is this statement a syntax error when it is embedded in CommonForm.js, but not when it is embedded in the main file Person6.js?  There is nothing in front of the imports in either file but comments.  Apparently because of this error in the imported file the main file is never executed.  I put an alert just after the imports and it did not pop.

I am trying to migrate my code from ES3 to ES6.  How do I fix this error?

Comment: Unless you've set up eslint to explicitly validate import targets, it does not check this type of thing. Are you sure `http.js` has a default export?

Comment: I clearly do not know what I am doing.  The first few non-comment lines of http.js are: export var HTTP;
if (HTTP && (typeof HTTP != "object" || HTTP.NAME))
    throw new Error("Namespace 'HTTP' already exists");

// Create our namespace, and specify some meta-information
window.HTTP = HTTP = {};   The question however is why is the import a syntax error in CommonForm.js but is valid in Person6.js when it is exactly the same line!

Comment: I have explicitly run eslint against each of the files individually, so if there really WAS a syntax error in CommonForm.js why did eslint not flag it when I pointed it at CommonForm.js?

Comment: ESLint runs on individual files to check their syntax. This error is not syntax-related, and would require it to read and process multiple files and how they are connected. You would need to install and enable https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import for that to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import HTTP from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
```

is the equivalent of

```
import { default as HTTP } from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
```

and your error

```
import not found: default
```

is saying that `http.js` does not have a `default` export. With the snippet you posted, that is indeed the case.

```
export var HTTP; 
if (HTTP && (typeof HTTP != "object" || HTTP.NAME)) 
  throw new Error("Namespace 'HTTP' already exists"); // Create our namespace, and specify some meta-information 
window.HTTP = HTTP = {};
```

does not have a default export, is has an `HTTP` export, For your code to work as-is, you would need to do

```
import { HTTP as HTTP } from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
// or shortened
import { HTTP } from "../jscripts6/js20/http.js";
```

it is also worth noting that

```
if (HTTP && (typeof HTTP != "object" || HTTP.NAME))
```

in this context will *never* evaluate to `true` and will *never* throw, because you're explicitly declaring it as `undefined` by not providing a value in the `export var HTTP;` declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation.  My imports and exports all seem to work now.  If the problem was not a syntax error why does the code throw a SyntaxError?     "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default CommonForm.js:157:7."

Comment: I think the best answer there is "because JS decided to consider that a syntax error". It's certainly debatable, but at the end of the day it is what it is.