# Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I'm trying to make the backend for my webapp with nodejs and express. The page worked fine on the parcel dev server. I'm getting this import not found on one of the 2 modules I'm using, the other seems to work fine.

The app.js

```js
const express = require("./node_modules/express/index.js");
const app = express();
const ejs = require("./node_modules/ejs/ejs.js")
const path = require("node:path")



app.use("/", express.static("public"));
app.use("/tonal", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs/tonal/dist")))
app.use("/tonal2", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs")))
app.use("/note", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs/note/dist")))
app.use("/chord", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs/chord/dist")))
app.use("/scale", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs/scale/dist")))
app.use("/interval", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/@tonaljs/interval/dist")))
app.use("/vexflow", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/node_modules/vexflow/build/esm/src")))
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/images")))





app.use("*", async(req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://ejercicios-de-armonia.herokuapp.com")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization")
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'")
  next()
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("armonia.ejs")
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1234, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 1234")
})
```

The imports in the js file

```
import { Note, Chord, Scale, Interval } from "/tonal/index.js"
import { Vex, Stave, StaveNote, Formatter, Voice, KeySignature} from "/vexflow/index.js"
```

the folder structure

- node_modules

  - @tonaljs

    - note
    - chord
    - interval
    - scale
    - tonal
  - vexflow
- public

  - scripts

    - armonia.js (main js file)
  - styles

    - armonia.css
- views

  - armonia.ejs
- app.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646969/uncaught-syntaxerror-import-not-found-default-works-in-one-module-and-not-in

Comment: @ChrisG The fix suggested is using 
´import { Note} from "/tonal/index.js"´ 
instead of 
´import Note from "/tonal/index.js"´
which I already do. Or am i not understanding it?

Comment: It probably should be `import { Note, Chord, Scale, Interval } from "@tonaljs"` (same for the vexflow module)

Comment: @ChrisG But then I get the "module should start with '/', './' or '../' " error. Is there a way to avoid that error importing from "@tonaljs"? Thanks

Comment: Oh I see, you're trying to use these modules client-side directly. I'd use this: https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal#browser then do `const { Note, Chord, Scale, Interval } = Tonal;`